# VueJs 2 computed value cant read data

Tags: vuejs2, vuex

I'm trying to make a component for a login view. My app is really simple right now as I'm trying to learn Vue/Vuex.

In the sign in component, I want to check if the email is valid, using a computed value.

```
var emailRE = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

export default {
  name: "SignIn",
  data: () => {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isValidEmail: () => {
      return emailRE.test(this.email);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    signIn() {
      if (this.isValidEmail) {
        this.$store.dispatch("signIn", {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

However, the `isValidEmail` function throws an error in the console:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'email' of undefined

Why can't my computed value read the this.email?

PS: I had to use data as a function according to the guidelines.

Comment: `isValidEmail: () => {}` should be `isValidEmail () => {}` (remove the ":")

Comment: My syntaxe used ( without arrow function ) : 
`export default {  data ()  { return {} }, computed: { isValidEmail () {} }, methods: { signIn () {} } }`

Comment: It worked! I feel lost with all the syntax change. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the comments:

> Actually, VSCode won't complain as there is no syntax error in your
>   code but its a wrong usage of the arrow function. In fact Vuejs docs
>   warns us against using arrow functions in the vue components
>   properties vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks .
>   For more on arrow function and 'this' usage check this article.
>   medium.freecodecamp.org/… . Its a 5 minute read article very plainly
>   written with nice example.

This now works:

```
var emailRE = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@\"]+)*)|(\".+\"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

export default {
  name: "SignIn",
  data () {
    return {
      email: "",
      password: ""
    };
  },
  computed: {
    isValidEmail () {
      return emailRE.test(this.email);
    }
  },
  methods: {
    signIn () {
      if (this.isValidEmail) {
        this.$store.dispatch("signIn", {
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password
        });
      }
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: Actually, VSCode won't complain as there is no syntax error in your code but its a wrong usage of the arrow function. In fact Vuejs docs warns us against using arrow functions in the vue components properties https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Instance-Lifecycle-Hooks . For more on arrow function and 'this' usage check this article. https://medium.freecodecamp.org/learn-es6-the-dope-way-part-ii-arrow-functions-and-the-this-keyword-381ac7a32881 . Its a 5 minute read article very plainly written with nice example.

Comment: Thanks, I'll update my answer. Unless you want to post an answer then I can accept it.